# JSF RichFaces a4j parallel ajax calls

Tags: java, richfaces, ajax4jsf

### The Problem

I'd like to re-render parts/elements of a JSF page on a JS event individually. I could easily attach an

```
<a4j:ajax render="one two three" />
```

to the event issuer or use an

```
<a4j:jsFunction render="one two three" name="load" />
```

but these methods issue only one request and render everything after response from server. What I want instead is parallel requests and asynchronous rendering.

### What I've tried so far

**Multiple ajax elements**

I've tried with multiple ajax elements with a different render attribute value each, but this way I get X requests and responses which all contain the data for ALL elements that need re-rendering:

```
<a4j:ajax render="one" />
<a4j:ajax render="two" />
<a4j:ajax render="three" />
```

---

**Multiple jsFunction elements**

Using multiple jsFunction works in sense of individual calls and separate rendering, but the requests are only issued after the last one has been answered, which is more like sequential loading (I've measured using browser dev tools):

```
<a4j:jsFunction render="one" name="loadOne" />
<a4j:jsFunction render="two" name="loadTwo" />
<a4j:jsFunction render="three" name="loadThree" />
```

The last method looks most promising, as the functions ARE asynchronous (they return immediately), but the requests seem to be all in one queue and they're processed sequentially instead of parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reviving an old question here...

Long story short: this is not possible since JSF is strictly sequential. Period.